Getting the maximum value from column in Pyspark
I have a table and would like to get the record of the maximum Course_Fees
I created the query:
course_df.select("Name", "Duration_Months", "Payment_Done").where(f.col("Course_Fees") == course_df.select(f.max("Course_Fees")).show()

with intention of getting 6000 as a result, but I get the error:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

I then decided to first create placeholder like:
maximumCourseFee = course_df.select(f.max("Course_Fees"))
maximumCourseFee.show()

then changed my query to:
course_df.select("Name", "Duration_Months", "Payment_Done").where(f.col("Course_Fees") == maximumCourseFee).show()

and I got this:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

but when I created the query in this format it works
course_df.select("Name", "Duration_Months", "Payment_Done").where(f.col("Course_Fees") == 60000).show()


minimal runnable code? inputs and expected outputs?

Here your variable 'maximumCourseFee' is a dataframe and not an integer. Try modifying the maximumCourseFee variable to this, and it should work.
maximumCourseFee = course_df.select(f.max("Course_Fees")).collect()[0][0]


Note that the question calls show against maximumCourseFee, so it is not expecting an integer. The answer may need another intermediate variable. You might need to modify a different expression. The original question also attracted criticism that the code excerpts were too minimal for anyone to try reproducing. Your answer might need to show / to modify a few lines, rather than just a single line.
